# Calculate average of month and replace values of other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below:

```
vdate=c("12-04-2015","13-04-2015","14-04-2015","15-04-2015","12-05-2015","13-05-2015","14-05-2015"
    ,"15-05-2015","12-06-2015","13-06-2015","14-06-2015","15-06-2015")
month=c(4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
col1=c(12,12.4,14.3,3,5.3,1.8,7.6,4.5,7.6,10.7,12,15.7)

df=data.frame(vdate,month,col1)
```

Below is the column which contains value based on some calculation:

```
pvar=c(8.4,2.4,12,14.4,2.3,3.5,7.8,5,16,5.4,18,18.4)
```

**Now I want to replace pvar value if its value less than the average value for that particular month.**

```
For example,
for month 4,
Average value of pvar is 9.3 ((8.4+2.4+12+14.4)/4).
```

**Then replace all the value in pvar which is less than avg for month 4 that is (8.4 &2.4).**
    Pvar value would be 9.3,9.3,12,14.4

I need to do this for all the values in pvar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` based solution could be :

```
  #Additional condition has been added to check if month != 6
  cbind(df, pvar) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(pvar = ifelse(pvar < mean(pvar) & month != 6, mean(pvar), pvar))  %>% 
  as.data.frame()

# vdate month col1  pvar
# 1  12-04-2015     4 12.0  9.30
# 2  13-04-2015     4 12.4  9.30
# 3  14-04-2015     4 14.3 12.00
# 4  15-04-2015     4  3.0 14.40
# 5  12-05-2015     5  5.3  4.65
# 6  13-05-2015     5  1.8  4.65
# 7  14-05-2015     5  7.6  7.80
# 8  15-05-2015     5  4.5  5.00
# 9  12-06-2015     6  7.6 16.00
# 10 13-06-2015     6 10.7  5.40
# 11 14-06-2015     6 12.0 18.00
# 12 15-06-2015     6 15.7 18.40
```

**Data**

```
vdate=c("12-04-2015","13-04-2015","14-04-2015","15-04-2015","12-05-2015",
        "13-05-2015","14-05-2015","15-05-2015","12-06-2015","13-06-2015",
        "14-06-2015","15-06-2015")
month=c(4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
col1=c(12,12.4,14.3,3,5.3,1.8,7.6,4.5,7.6,10.7,12,15.7)

df=data.frame(vdate,month,col1)
pvar=c(8.4,2.4,12,14.4,2.3,3.5,7.8,5,16,5.4,18,18.4)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I want to add where clause on month too. For example I need to do this where month=4 and 5 NOT for 6. Could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: @user15051990 Updated answer to apply checking for `mean` for month other than `6`. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Small observation here. `month != 6` is an overfit. If there are more months, then those will not be excluded. You could say `month %in% c(4, 5)`. Good solution though...

Comment: @Sotos Thanks much. Your suggestion is appropriate as `month != 6` is too restrictive. But I read `OP` comments like `NOT for 6`. That's why I had modified answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution would be to use `ave`. Note that we first need to convert the date column to actual date in order to extract the month (`strsplit` or regex can also do it but I prefer to have it set as a proper date), i.e.

```
df$vdate <- as.POSIXct(df$vdate, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
with(df, ave(pvar, format(vdate, '%m'), FUN = function(i) replace(i, i < mean(i), mean(i))))
 #[1]  9.30  9.30 12.00 14.40  4.65  4.65  7.80  5.00 16.00 14.45 18.00 18.40
```

As per your edit, I will use [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to tackle it as it might be more readable. There are actually two ways I came up with.

**First**: Create an extra grouping variable that will put all the months you need to alter the values in the same group and replace from there, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

cbind(df, pvar) %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(!month %in% c(4, 5))+1, month) %>% 
 mutate(pvar = replace(pvar, pvar < mean(pvar), mean(pvar))) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

**Second**: Filter the months you need, do the calculations. Then filter the months you don't need, create again the `pvar` but without changing anything (necessary for binding the rows) and bind the rows, i.e.

```
bind_rows(
  cbind(df, pvar) %>%
    filter(month %in% c(4, 5)) %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    mutate(pvar = replace(pvar, pvar < mean(pvar), mean(pvar))),
  cbind(df, pvar) %>%
    filter(!month %in% c(4, 5))
)
```

**Both the above give,**

> ```
>    vdate      month  col1  pvar
>    <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 12-04-2015    4. 12.0  12.0 
>  2 13-04-2015    4. 12.4  12.4 
>  3 14-04-2015    4. 14.3  14.3 
>  4 15-04-2015    4.  3.00 10.4 
>  5 12-05-2015    5.  5.30  5.30
>  6 13-05-2015    5.  1.80  4.80
>  7 14-05-2015    5.  7.60  7.60
>  8 15-05-2015    5.  4.50  4.80
>  9 12-06-2015    6.  7.60  7.60
> 10 13-06-2015    6. 10.7  10.7 
> 11 14-06-2015    6. 12.0  12.0 
> 12 15-06-2015    6. 15.7  15.7
> ```

Comment: Thanks!! I want to add where clause on month too. For example I need to do this where month=4 and 5. Could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: @Sotos Seems you have made it too complicated:-) . One minor point your initial solution was excellent but in recent edit it seems you have not considered `pvar` array which `OP` wanted to be processed. Perhaps by mistake your calculations had been on based on `col1`. Please have a look.

Comment: @MKR Indeed. Thanks for noticing